# Ember.View.reopen() for binding data-* attribute doesn't work any longer since I updated ember version to 1.13.3

Tags: ember.js

some code from guide

```
Ember.View.reopen({
  init: function() {
    this._super();
    var self = this;

    // bind attributes beginning with 'data-'
    Ember.keys(this).forEach(function(key) {
      if (key.substr(0, 5) === 'data-') {
        self.get('attributeBindings').pushObject(key);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

not work

even place attributeBindings directly

```
Ember.View.reopen({
  attributeBindings: ['data-some', ...]
});
```

not work

```
Ember.TextField.reopen({
    attributeBindings: ['data-some', ...],
});
```

work for input helper

ember 1.13.3

ember-data 1.13.5

ember-cli 1.13.1

Help

Do I miss something?

Comment: So, where is the value for the attribute binding of `data-some` coming from? Is there a property on your model called `data-some`? If the attribute binding has no value (undefined), Ember will ignore it. How was this working **before** the upgrade? Do non-data-* attributes work?

Comment: I use attribute binding for input helper mostly. I just put that code form guide in application route, then start to use data-* attributes before the upgrade. I find that Ember.keys(this) aren't those data-* attributes but attributes of View class, like     childViews ownerView classNameBindings classNames ...

Comment: In the other word, how do I access these data-* attributes since Ember.keys(this) don't contan them.

Comment: Where do the `data-*` attributes come from? Where are they defined?

Comment: input helper, mostly like {{input data-parsley-required="true"}}

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**
Looks like a confirmed regression in 1.13 -
https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/11480

---

(removed original answer because I was mistaken)

Comment: The document you quote does not state that `attributeBindings` are deprecated. Furthermore "deprecated" does not mean "doesn't work any more"; it means "it will stop working in the future".

Comment: You're right - looks like this is a confirmed regression in 1.13 -

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/11480

Answer (score 1):

Answer from ember.js issue
[Ember.View is being deprecated](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/11849)